# Performance of the new user drop down information

Tags: support, status-completed, activity

I mostly use mobile broadband to access this (and other) sites. As such the connection speed and signal strength are very variable. (I do wish mobile broadband was 1/10 [1/100] as good as it is advertised.) The one element of the site that seems to magnify such variability is the new activity drop down. When signal strength is weak this can take up to a minute and a half to populate and display. This does of course make the feature a positive handicap in using the site as a whole.

Could the performance of this feature be investigated and improved please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not your connection (completely, at least). This is on our end, it's the result of about a dozen things, all of which we're improving.  In fact, @[waffles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/17174/waffles) just pushed a change that dramatically decreases the cost of us finding revisions to your posts, this will speed things up another level.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact, on both my DSL and cable lines the dropdown speed is poor, so it's probably more related to the SO servers than to your uplink.

And when it pops up, all it does is make the original mail icon look super-fantastic.

(And my favorite browser refuses to render the dropdown at all.)

Answer (score 1):

I find this also, and I haven't been able to figure how to get to the page that the mail icon took you to.

Comment: It's at http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent

Comment: @Cameron: is there a direct link to that somewhere on the site or do I have to type that every time?

Comment: @alex That page will give a 404 eventually. It's deprecated and will be removed entirely.